# jQuery - iframe src from input - multiple instances

Tags: jquery

I have the `iframe` receiving it's `src` from the `input` for each instance of the `.item` but I think my code is iterating over every instance of `.item` whenever a `keyup` happens.

How do I modify the code to only execute on the `.item` for which the `input` of that item is being changed? I want to have it where the `iframe` appears after the url has been copy / pasted. It doesn't have to be on keyup but whenever the url is successfully entered -> show the `iframe`.

**Bonus requirement** :: I only want to show the iframe if it has a `value` entered in it's associated `input`, either on load or when the link has been entered.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/moofawsaw/pen/wvGNvrx

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  iframeKeyup();

  function getId(url) {
    var regExp = /^.*(youtu.be\/|v\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|watch\?v=|\&v=)([^#\&\?]*).*/;
    var match = url.match(regExp);

    if (match && match[2].length == 11) {
      return match[2];
    } else {
      return "error";
    }
  }
  $("input").on("keyup change", function() {
    iframeKeyup();
  });

  var myId;

  function iframeKeyup() {
    $(".item").each(function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      var myUrl = $this.find("input").val();
      myId = getId(myUrl);
      $this
        .find(".iframe")
        .html(
          '<iframe width="100%" height="100" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/' +
          myId +
          '" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'
        );
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.item {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 1.3rem
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
  <input type="text" value="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I7QJkecUpi8" />
  <div class="iframe"></div>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <input type="text" value="" />
  <div class="iframe"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Doing this while user types makes no sense. Will be making numerous bad requests to youtube while they type. Only set iframe when they are done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the parent element to your `iframeKeyup` and then find the `iframe` to be load only when to to the actually typed input on `paste` or `input`.

Also, to check if input is `empty` to just `check` if its has `val()` or else make the `iframe` empty again.

**Edit:** Since you want to load the `iframe` if input has a default value then you need to set a `flag` and pass `true` to `false` when you call your `iframeKeyup`  which will check whether its a typed input `iframe` load or is it just onload `iframe` -

**Live Demo:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  iframeKeyup(false)

  function getId(url) {
    var regExp = /^.*(youtu.be\/|v\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|watch\?v=|\&v=)([^#\&\?]*).*/;
    var match = url.match(regExp);

    if (match && match[2].length == 11) {
      return match[2];
    } else {
      return "error";
    }
  }
  $("input").on("input paste", function() {
    var parent = $(this).parent()
    iframeKeyup(true, parent); //pass the parent on input or paste
  });

  var myId;

  function iframeKeyup(isTyped, parent = null) {
    if (isTyped) {
      loadiFrame(parent)
    } else {
      $(".item").each(function(index, element) {
        var $item = $(element);
        loadiFrame($item)
      })
    }
  }

  function loadiFrame(parent) {
    var myUrl = parent.find("input").val();
    if (myUrl != '') {
      myId = getId(myUrl);
      parent
        .find(".iframe")
        .html(
          '<iframe width="100%" height="100" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/' +
          myId +
          '" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'
        );
    } else {
      parent
        .find(".iframe")
        .html('')
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.item {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 1.3rem
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
  <input type="text" value="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I7QJkecUpi8" />
  <div class="iframe"></div>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <input type="text" value="" />
  <div class="iframe"></div>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <input type="text" value="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I7QJkecUpi8" />
  <div class="iframe"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Would you be able to run this on load for the value's that are already filled in the input?

Comment: @KyleUnderhill Answer updated and working for input with default values as well as showing the relevant iframe to the typed input value or when a url is pasted.